# Javascript function runs twice when validating form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sure there must be a simple explanation to this. I'm trying to get an alert 'Country must be selected' to appear whenever the option 'Not Selected' is selected (it is selected by default I believe), and clicking on the **validation button**. I have been able to get the function to show the alert correctly, but the problem is that the alert shows twice.

Why does the alert show twice, and how can I get it to show only once? thanks!

```js
function CountrySelectValidation() { // ensures country is selected
 var ValidateCountry = document.forms["registration-form"]["Country"].value;
 if (ValidateCountry == "not-selected") {
  alert("Country must be selected");
  return false;
 } else {
  return true;
 }
}

function SubmitForm() {
    if (CountrySelectValidation()) {
        // check if true, then execute this code
        document.getElementById("registration-form").submit(); 
    }
}
```

```html
<form id="registration-form">
    What country are you from?
    <select name="Country">
  <option value="not-selected">Not Selected</option>
  <option value="england">England</option>
  <option value="wales">Wales</option>
  <option value="scotland">Scotland</option>
  <option value="northern-ireland">Northern Ireland</option>
 </select>
    <br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit Method 1">
    <button type="reset">Reset Method 1</button>
    <button type="submit" id="submit-2">Submit Method 2</button>
</form>

<button onClick="ResetForm()">Reset Method 1</button>
<button onClick="CountrySelectValidation(); SubmitForm()">Validation</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing the function again when you  call the if statement. Run the code from the if statement in a different function called inside the original function.

```
OriginalFunction () {

      //Content here

      FunctionToHandleIfstatement();

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CountrySelectValidation()
...
if (CountrySelectValidation())
```

You run the `CountrySelectValidation` function inside the `if` (it actually executes), so that's why it runs twice.